# Common input method to support different Brand's Bluetooth Printers in Android

Tags: android, printing, bluetooth

I am doing some R&D on supporting different company's Bluetooth Printers. I am able to make a connection with the printers which is already paired with my android device via Bluetooth and able to print the text also.

But the **input string format** is varying from one printer to another. All the printers are not behaving same, yes it wont.

Currently I have the separate API for each printers, But Is there any way to do the same thing in single API? If it is not suppose to achieve this by a single API, Please suggest the way to approach this.

I am using **BluetoothAdapter** to get the paired devices and using **BluetoothSocket** to make a connection.

As of now, I am using **Bixolon**, **Zebra** and **Intermec** printers

Please let me know if need of any further information.

Comment: you can't do this ... thats why [drivers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_driver) were made... you have to build common interface then make an implementation of it for every hardware interface(i'm pretty sure that some of zebras are using the same apis) then make a Factory to choose right implementation based on some hardware id ...

Comment: @Selvin Thank you for your valuable input. I will approach on that way also. Thanks.

Comment: it is only a concept : https://gist.github.com/SelvinPL/3416c8fb69e83230d1e3